# What is a value in food that I should eat during sitting?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Minor healing potion restores 120 health
Linen bandage: 96 health during 6 seconds
Spice bread: restores 96 health over 18 seconds, must remain seated while eating.

What is a value in food that I should eat during siting? The only problem with health I have is during the battle, otherwise a have no problem with health.

What is a point to sit and eat when you have enough health?

Comment: Could you include some specific item names and maybe wowhead.com links to the items? I suspect your confusing food and bandages. Also, by Stamina, do you mean Mana?

Comment: Yes, sorry, provided.

Comment: Unless it is food with a stat bonus, food has next to no value while you are leveling up. However, IMO you should still level up your cooking because the end-game recipes are well worth it once you hit level 85 to 90.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the reason you don't see the value of food is that you're playing a low level character, and thus, benefitting from the substantially faster out-of-combat health regen afforded to low level characters. As you level up, you'll find that you regenerate health out of combat much more slowly, and you'll want to use food to speed things up and reduce your downtime between fights.

The advantage of food over bandages or potions is that food 1) is substantially cheaper and easier to acquire in large quantities 2) restores substantially more health, faster, and 3) does not invoke any sort of cool down, whereas bandages and potions do.

Comment: Food also provides some stats in many instances!

Comment: Adding to this answer and the comment above, in end-game play, the stat bonuses you get from food are considered very important in dungeons and raids.

Comment: @JensenChing Very much so. My old guild used to kick people from their raid groups if they didn't come with food. Which was a bit extreme, given the Mage food stuffs.

Comment: @Fluttershy, mage food only provides recovery, not buffs.